# Expectation of an average-centralised sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independently identically distributed random variables with $EX = \mu$ and $\text{Var} X= \sigma^2$. Let:
$$\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k,$$
$$m_n^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n(X_k - \bar{X}_n)^2.$$
Prove that $E(m_n^2) = \sigma^2 \frac{n-1}{n}$.

This is a problem from Allan Gut's *Probability - A Graduate Course*, and after messing around with the sums for a while I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You might want to replace $X_k-\bar X_n$ with $(X_k-\mu) -\frac1n\sum_j(X_j-\mu)$, and then multiply out the square keeping the brackets, and then take the expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe that $X_k-\overline{X_n}$ has the same distribution as $X_n-\overline{X_n}$ (this is just a matter of permuting the involved random variables). As a consequence, $m_n^2=\mathbb E\left[\left(X_n-\overline{X_n}\right)^2\right]=\operatorname{Var}\left(X_n-\overline{X_n}\right)$.
2. Write $X_n-\overline{X_n}=X_n\left(1-1/n\right)+\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i$ and use the property $\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}\left(Y_i\right)$, valid for an independent collection $\left(Y_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ of random variables.